# R sum of columns divided by number of columns without NA

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

i cant seem to figure this out. What i want to do is make a new column in my dataframe with the sum of several columns divided by the number of columns which constribute to the sum.
so like this:

```
ID  2003    2004    2005    2006
1   1   4   1   NA
2   2   2   NA  3
3   1   3   NA  NA
4   4   1   1   NA
5   3   1   4   2
```

to this:

```
ID  2003    2004    2005    2006    SUM/col
1   1   4   1   NA  2
2   2   2   NA  3   2.33
3   1   3   NA  NA  2
4   4   1   1   NA  3
5   3   1   4   2   2.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `rowMeans` function and set `na.rm = TRUE`. `dt[, -1]` is a way to exclude the first column for the analysis.

```
dt$`SUM/col` <- rowMeans(dt[, -1], na.rm = TRUE)
dt
  ID X2003 X2004 X2005 X2006  SUM/col
1  1     1     4     1    NA 2.000000
2  2     2     2    NA     3 2.333333
3  3     1     3    NA    NA 2.000000
4  4     4     1     1    NA 2.000000
5  5     3     1     4     2 2.500000
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "ID  2003    2004    2005    2006
1   1   4   1   NA
                 2   2   2   NA  3
                 3   1   3   NA  NA
                 4   4   1   1   NA
                 5   3   1   4   2",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `data.frame` is called `df`, then try:

```
df$"SUM/col" <- apply(df, 1, function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T))
```

The `apply` function calculates, for each row, the sum (excluding `NA`s) divided by the total number of non-`NA` elements. The resulting vector is then added as a column to `df`.

Comment: Or `apply(df, 1, mean, na.rm = T)`